# Perl regex swap matched groups

Tags: regex, perl

I've come up with a regex that parses output of GPG command.

**Regex:**

```
^pub\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+.*\s+.{0,32}(.*)\s+(.*)<(\S+)>
```

**Text to match:**

```
pub   dsa1024 2018-02-28 [SCA]
      0019003A003E5A22E2337044D955066111F63B00
uid           [ unknown] John Doe <jogn@doe.name>
sub   elg1024 2018-02-28 [E]
```

**Current output:**

```
Group 1.    6-13    dsa1024
Group 2.    14-24   2018-02-28
Group 3.    69-77   11F63B00
Group 4.    78-112  uid           [ unknown] John Doe 
Group 5.    113-126 jogn@doe.name
```

---

**Problem:**

How do I swap *Group 2* and *Group 3*, only using regex, so *Group 2* would have as a value *11F63B00* and *Group 3* would have as a value *2018-02-28*. Besides, I would also like to get rid of the text in square brackets (*Group 4*), including brackets itself.

[Online example.](https://regex101.com/r/h9g9mE/1)

Comment: Why not use named capturing groups?

Comment: We use named groups in the code later but it's part of already existing code that has exactly reversed output, on previous GPG versions.

Comment: You should probably mention in the question why you need to swap these groups at all. Maybe there is an entirely different solution to your problem.

Comment: In Webmin we need to support multiple versions of GPG command output to parse data out of it. We could change the initial code but the interesting part would be to achieve this without doing it, using only regex. There might be different kind of output changes in the future. Changing/adding new regex is the best and easiest solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The captured strings are returned in the order encountered in which the captures are found in the pattern.

It is possible to change the order using lookaheads.

```
/
   ^ pub \s+ (\S+) \s+ 
   (?=  \S+  \s+ .* \s+ .{0,32}(.*) \s+  .*  < \S+ > )
       (\S+) \s+ .* \s+ .{0,32} .*  \s+ (.*) <(\S+)>
/x
```

If we express that in terms of lines, we get the following:

```
/
   ^ pub \h++ (\S++) \h++       # Line 1 (part 1)
   (?= .*+ \n                   # Line 1 (part 2)
       \h*+ \S*(\S{8})          # Line 2
   )
   (\S++) .*+ \n                # Line 1 (part 2)
   .*+ \n                       # Line 2
   (.*\S) \s++ <([^<>\s]++)>    # Line 3
/x
```

(I also made it so match failures fail to match faster out of habit.)

(`\S{32}` would be faster than `\S*` if that's acceptable.)

(I also made it so the fourth capture doesn't have trailing spaces.)

---

That said, a far better solution is to fix the order after the fact.

```
@captures = @captures[0,2,1,3,4];
```

or

```
@captures[1,2] = @captures[2,1];
```

Comment: I have tried your regex, thanks a lot by the way. The date is missing though: https://regex101.com/r/Jwpp5d/1

Comment: Misplaced the parens. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better way to catch last 8 chars of the key string (the one that is 40 chars)? The regex is failing in my Perl script, returning empty, while it works okay in 101regex. I need to do more tests. Is there a way to strip out from results `[ unknown]` or any text in brackets including the brackets?

Comment: Re "*The regex is failing in my Perl script*", That would suggest a difference in the data.

Comment: Re "*Is there a way to strip out from results [...] any text in brackets including the brackets?*", Only if it's at the start/end of a field. (It's not in your example.) Then you could start capturing later or stop capturing sooner.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the explanations and your help! ☺

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing but in Perl script, the key is missing (returns empty)? :/ In the code it's clear as day, that second matching group is assigned.
https://github.com/webmin/webmin/blob/master/webmin/gnupg-lib.pl#L32

Comment: That's not the proper way to ask a question. I'm not even sure how it relates to this question!

Comment: Okay, I agree. Apologies. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in `d` file

```
perl -ane 'if($F[1]==2) {$n=<>;@k=split /\s+/,$n;@j=split /\s+/;s/$j[3]/$k[3]/;$n=~s/$k[3]/$j[3]/;print "$_$n" } else {s/\[.*\].+//;print}' d
```